# 'ImportError: no module named admin' when trying to follow the Django Girls tutorial

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am currently doing the Django Girls tutorial, and I have hit a road block in which I can't `python manage.py migrate` because bash complains that there aren't any modules named admin. What can I do? I have done everything as the tutorial said. I am running bash through pythonanywhere.com, and this the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                          
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>                                    
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                     
  File "/home/wost/my-new-blog/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djan
go/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line     
    utility.execute()                                                       
  File "/home/wost/my-new-blog/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djan
go/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute                       
    django.setup()                                                          
  File "/home/wost/my-new-blog/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djan
go/__init__.py", line 18, in setup                                          
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)                                  
  File "/home/wost/my-new-blog/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djan
go/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate                                  
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)                                    
  File "/home/wost/my-new-blog/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djan
go/apps/config.py", line 123, in create                                     
    import_module(entry)                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)                                                        
ImportError: No module named admin
```

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on the same thing; the problem was the statement in urls.py:

```
path('admin/', include('admin.site.urls'))
```

Instead the right line is

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have the following in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "admin",
    # ...
]
```

I think you meant to use `django.contrib.admin` instead:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "django.contrib.admin",
    # ...
]
```

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` has only got 'django.contrib.admin', there are no 'admin' there. :/

Comment: @gloriousCatnip how about you remove the `settings.pyc` and try migrating again? thanks.

Comment: Nope, still the same problem! :(

Comment: @gloriousCatnip okay, is this the step you are currently stuck at: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/? And you are getting this error when running `python manage.py migrate blog`?

Comment: I am stuck here, when trying to run `python manage.py migrateblog`: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/#creating-the-database-on-pythonanywhere

Everything else have worked flawlessly.

Comment: @gloriousCatnip do you have that `admin.py` in your app dir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110033/discussion-between-gloriouscatnip-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no model like `admin` and you're still trying to import it. Post your `settings.py`. As I'm guessing you probably had added `admin` inside `INSTALLED_APP` like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'admin',
     .......
]
```

If it's then remove that `admin` and make it clear like assuming you haven't created any application in entire project

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

And second thing I'm thinkin' of is that you might not had activated your project's virtual environment. Sometimes, this causes probs like this. And for that just change `prompt` to where your `manage.py` is located and just hit `..\Scripts\activate`(Windows) or `../Scripts/activate`(Unix like OSs).

Comment: Reply something @gloriousCatnip

Comment: I have activated the shell's virtual environment, that I am sure off. 
The settings.py:
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog'
]  `
I was supposed to have the 'blog' there, as a part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns outs the problem is I was in the wrong virtual environment and the wrong path file. Confirm that and it might save you a lot of work in debugging and changing the code which was working initially.